# Entity Framework Core - Sqlite Exception: ROLLBACK

Tags: c#, exception, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I am occasionally encountering following error after shutting down and relaunching the application:

> SQLite Error 4: 'abort due to ROLLBACK'.

Especially this exception is occurring while calling this following query. It is the first query after launch inside a loop, however not necessary the first call which is causing the exception.

```
public ObservableCollection<Device> GetConnectedDevicesNoTracking(ConnectionPoint connectionPoint)
{
    var list = DatabaseContext.Devices
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(d => d.ConnectionPointDevices)
                    .ThenInclude(d => d.ConnectionPoint)
                    .Where(d => d.ConnectionPointDevices.Any(cpd => cpd.ConnectionPointId == connectionPoint.ConnectionPointId))
                    .Include(d => d.Supplier1)
                    .Include(d => d.CableType1)
                    .Include(d => d.Sockets)
                    .ToList();

    return new ObservableCollection<Device>(list);
}
```

Any tips how this should be avoided? There are no exceptions while calling `SaveChanges()` on the context.

The context saving method:

```
public int Complete()
{
    try
    {
        var count = _context.SaveChanges();
        return count;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Database Concurrency error while trying to save changes: ", ex);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Database error while trying to save changes: ", ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         throw new Exception("Database general error while trying to save changes: ", ex);
    }
}
```

**Exception details**

> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException was unhandled by user code
>   ErrorCode=-2147467259   HResult=-2147467259   Message=SQLite Error 4:
>   'abort due to ROLLBACK'.   Source=Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
>   SqliteErrorCode=4   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.MarshalEx.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc,
>   Sqlite3Handle db)
>          at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.Read()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_Include>d__30`1.MoveNext()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_Include>d__30`1.MoveNext()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_Include>d__30`1.MoveNext()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_Include>d__30`1.MoveNext()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at FxPlugin.Persistence.Repositories.ConnectionPointRepository.GetConnectedDevicesNoTracking(ConnectionPoint
>   connectionPoint) in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\FxEditorDatabaseStructure\FxEditorDatabaseStructure\Persistence\Repositories\ConnectionPointRepository.cs:line
>   168
>          at FxPlugin.ViewModels.ProjectDeviceDatabaseViewModel.InitialLoading_DoWork(Object
>   sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects\FxEditorDatabaseStructure\FxEditorDatabaseStructure\ViewModels\ProjectDeviceDatabaseViewModel.cs:line
>   488
>          at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
>          at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
>   argument)   InnerException:

Comment: What version of EF Core are you using; could this be issue [#5628](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5628)? If not, please [create a new issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/new).

Comment: I'm using versio of EF Core RC2

Comment: Then yes, it might be. Try upgrading to RTM.